# How can I find the Reviews for all the technical Books?

Tags: comments, review

Is there any site for technical books reviews and comments. So that it is very useful before reading the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use Amazon's reviews and whatever a search finds me. Ideally I like to see a review weigh up pros and cons with examples of both the good and the bad, rather than just saying "This book is great."

There's a problem with reviewing technical books though: if you don't know the topic, you can't judge how accurate the book is, but you get a rough idea of how well it explains things (in terms of whether or not you get lost). If you *do* know the topic, you can judge accuracy but you can't judge how useful it would be to a newbie. I've [blogged about this in more detail](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/07/08/the-trouble-with-book-reviews.aspx). (If you happen to want to read a review of any book I've reviewed, I have a [book review tag](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Book+reviews/default.aspx) on my blog. I tend to be harsher than most reviewers, partly because I have a very high standard for accuracy (not that I'm claiming to meet it myself), but I do at least explain why I do or don't like a book.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon.com?

Answer (score 0):

http://books.slashdot.org/